# Replacing the Picklist old values into new values?

Tags: apex, trigger, administration, picklist

We have a requirement to updated the picklist values to new values. We are doing it via "Replace".

Whenever we do this, will the updated record fire `Apex Triggers`, `Workflow Rules`, etc.?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, workflow rules, triggers, validation rules, flows, Process Builders, and any other logic that would run on a normal DML operation will not run as a result of using Replace.

Comment: Thnks for quick reply.,Is there any salesforce reference links related to this ?

Comment: @SUreshShettigar I don't remember where it's documented, but it's always been this way. Most "mass actions" you can do in setup won't activate any customizations or code.

Comment: @SUreshShettigar There are a few special exceptions noted in [the help document](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_replace.htm&type=0&language=en_US), such as updating StageName will also update Probability, Forecast Category, and Expected Revenue. Also mentioned is that Last Modified By fields will also be updated. However, no customization or code will run as a result of the replace feature.

Answer (score 2):

You can prove it yourself with a simple demo trigger:

```
trigger MyObject on MyObject__c (before update)
{
    for (MyObject__c record : trigger.new)
        if (trigger.oldMap.get(record.Id).Picklist__c != record.Picklist__c)
            record.addError('Cannot change picklist');
}
```

I ran a `Replace` on the `MyObject__c.Picklist__c` field with this trigger in place and the records successfully updated. Note that the `LastModifiedDate` value changes, as indicated in [Difference between Renaming a Picklist and Replacing a Picklist Value](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000175633&language=en_US):

> *Note: This is a global change and will replace the picklist value for all existing records, including records in the recycle bin. Also, this will update the Modified By date and time for all records where the value was replaced. Replacing / Renaming a pick list value will not update the record history related list*